# Angular getting unexpected/unexplained null reference

Tags: angular

I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'markAsPristine' of null' errors that are totally unexpected and make no sense.  This works 99% of the time, but on rare occasion, I get null reference errors on the markAsPristine.  I don't get how it can ever be null on that line.  Any ideas?

I marked the line with the error below.  But if you follow the code, it should be impossible that that line is null.  Just follow the code down.

Here is my code.

```
var parent = this;
this._contactService.saveContact(this.subscriberCode, this.contactId, {
  firstName: this.pageForm.controls.firstName.value,  /* This line works, so pageForm is not null here */
  lastName: this.pageForm.controls.lastName.value,
  address1: this.pageForm.controls.address1.value,
  address2: this.pageForm.controls.address2.value,
  city: this.pageForm.controls.city.value,
  state: this.pageForm.controls.state.value,
  zipCode: this.pageForm.controls.zipCode.value
})
  .subscribe(response => {
    parent.pageForm.markAsPristine();  /* this is where we get the error */
    this.messageAlert = 'Changes have been saved';
  }, (respError: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    this.messageAlert = this._errorReportService.formatResponseError(respError, `savePage()`);
  });
```

Comment: parent.pageForm is not null at the time that you invoke `this._contactService.saveContact`, but is it definitely still not null at the later time that the (asynchronous) response is received?

Comment: Correct.  How is that possible?  How can it have a value when I invoke 'saveContact', yet, be null inside of the 'subscribe'?

We know for sure it's not null at time of the 'saveContact', if it were, the .saveContact would blow up on a null reference error.

Comment: In the intervening time between calling saveContact and the subscribe coming back, could something else have happened to parent.pageForm to make it null? What about if instead of setting `var parent = this;`, you set `var pageForm = this.pageForm;` at the start, and then inside the subscribe do `pageForm.markAsPristine();`? Maybe the key is in the code immediately following the subscribe, which will execute immediately after the call to saveContact. Is there anything happening there which could make parent.pageForm null?

Comment: Nothing happens after the subscriber, it's the end of the method.
This particular screen is a popup.
I suppose it's possible the user could navigate to a new page, or click the 'x' to close the popup.

Comment: In that case, there's no harm if the popup is gone, right?  You could just check if parent.pageForm is not null before calling markAsPristine. I've used observables as described here https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject to display messages in other components, such as the page you return to after the popup is closed.

Comment: That is how I am handling it.  But I would really like to know how it's possible.

Comment: Well, the call to saveContact is asynchronous, so as you say, the user could be closing the popup before the call returns and is handled by the subscribe, and what you've stored in `parent` might have been destroyed.

Comment: Yea, that is the only possible explanation.